# What is 'fix name' in Netbeans?

Tags: php, netbeans

I'm developing a website with Netbeans and sometimes a notice appears that says 'Fix name to...' but I don't understand what the meaning of 'Fix name' is or what its role is...

Could anybody explain to me its meaning, please?

Thanks!

Comment: Similar to this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721888/should-i-namespace-global-functions-in-php ?

Comment: it means : `change the false contents of name to ...`. After done so, the problem is `fixed`.

Comment: Have you considered to close the question? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the name of your application is different from the name in the netbeans.conf file you will get this error. The way to fix it is to open the netbeans.conf file and change the name to the current name of your application.

Comment: you should mention where is this netbeans.conf kept

Comment: From my research it depends on the version. So this is kind of a general answer.
{netbeans-installation-dir}/etc/netbeans.conf