# How to turn of "Fix Name To ..." hint in NetBeans?

Tags: php, netbeans, configuration

I just installed NetBeans 8.10 on Windows 10 (64-bit). Everything works fine, but I don't know, how to turn off hint in PHP files about renaming global functions.

[image]

I search in Tools > Options > Editor > Hints, but found nothing relevant...

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15840523/what-is-fix-name-in-netbeans

Answer (score 3):

Not the way you want but an option is ask someone to zip configuration options with export button (bottom left) in Tools > Options and import it with import near export one

**EDIT**: Tools > Options > Editor > Hints and Language PHP uncheck Error Control Operator Misused

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade to [NetBeans 8.1](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/81/) (currently in Beta).  The "Fix Name To" hints disappeared for me.

Comment: hoped for that, no change whatsoever

Comment: @sitilge Then you should make a minimal reproducible case and send a bug report. Hurry while it is still in Beta.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting another similar (if not identical) [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15840523/what-is-fix-name-in-netbeans)

> If the name of your application is different from the name in the netbeans.conf file you will get this error. The way to fix it is to open the netbeans.conf file and change the name to the current name of your application.

The location of `netbeans.conf` depends on your [build/system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447867/where-is-the-netbeans-config-file-netbeans-conf-located). Might be

```
C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.10\etc\netbeans.conf
```